# how do you get a checkstatechanged to work in vb?

Tags: vb.net

I have this code but whenever I run it I get the Total VHF.Text as 0

```
Private Sub Vehicle_Fuel_DriverCheckBox_CheckStateChanged(sender As Object, e As Event Args) Handles Vehicle_Fuel_DriverCheckBox.CheckStateChanged

    TotalVHF.Text = Val(TotalCashEmoluments.Text) * Val(0.125)

End Sub
```

Comment: In editing your post for you, I removed some spaces which looked like they should not be there in `Vehicle_Fuel_Driver Check Box . Check State Changed`. Please change it back if the spaces are there in your code (and if they are, they should not be).

Comment: @AndrewMorton there are no spaces in there i changed it and still it is not working

Comment: If you put [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) as the first line in your code it may point out enough problems (and possible solutions) for you to fix your code. Also, it is probably better to use [Decimal.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see if a number in the correct format has been entered into `TotalCashEmoluments`.